# Sticky button but only after user made a selection

Tags: forms, mobile, user-behavior, buttons, selection

I'm designing a screen where users have to:

1. Select a day
2. Select a time slot
3. Click a "Confirm" button (which is disabled until the user selects day and time).

I didn't want to make the button sticky because it would cover some of the time slots. Then I thought: **What if I make it sticky only after the user has selected the day and time slot?**

This way, if they didn't reached the botton of the page, they won't have to continue scrolling. The button would just appear when everything is ready to go.

I don't think I've seen this pattern before and I wanted to know your thoughts. So, what do you think? Thanks in advance.

A wireframe of the situation:

[image]

Comment: I think Gojek does this in GoFood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky button would be a better approach, coz there isn't a lot of info/selection the user has to perform for them to get to the button. Scroll would be an extra action they need to perform for the button to appear.

Once the user selects the 'DAY', it can collapse(probable into an editable action so they can change if needed) and just show the selected day instead of showing all the other days too. So the time slots can move up a bit and will no longer be hidden behind the CTA Button.

Comment: I like your proposal of collapsing the days after selection. We could go even further. By default, Day 1 (today) is selected, so in some cases users won't select any day and go for the time directly. Would you also collapse the days when user selects time directly? I think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting idea, though there's a potential for the user to scroll back up and hide the selected time, either because it's under the button, or off the screen.

You could make the button action dynamic based on the user's selection, such as "Confirm Day 1 at 12:00".

Comment: I like the idea of the dynamic button. 

Even if the user scroll back up they would have everything they need to move forward since the "Confirm" button just appeared (sticky), so, that's not really a problem, right?

Answer (score 1):

You (and the other commenters) are close.

Just solve the problem you just described. Make sure that the user always sees its selection before confirming. Add another sticky section (preferably above the sticky confirm button) where the current selection is displayed. Don't worry about the user not seeing things, he/she can always scroll.

[image]

For convenience you could automatically scroll to time after the day has been selected, but this might feel shaky for some users. Btw. many booking sites do this and probably use a sticky button too.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say that the idea proposed by **Peq** is the most convenient for me and covers user needs.
Just show your selected time and day in the window along with the confirm button. A window will appear after the selection, and the user will not lose sight of their settings even if they scroll.

As an addition to the interface, you can add a few, in my opinion, useful options. Such as the **time the hall is busy, or the choice of a specific table or type of table** (near the window, single, double ..).

Answer (score 0):

Upon selection of day and time, consider a **"sticky popup"**:

[image: sticky popup]

...and allow people to close, or even move, it. Also some instruction or call to action can be included.